# How to call a function corresponding to the current state of the object?

Tags: javascript

This object is a kind of abstraction of a real device.
If several buttons are pressed, the device gives a certain value. There are a lot of combinations, about 70.
How best to organize the code in this case? At first I wanted to use the switch construction, but when I counted the number of combinations, it seemed to me that this was a bad idea.

```
const device = {
    mode: false,
    zero: false,
    minus10: false,
    minus20: false,
    minus30: false,
    minus40: false,
    speed: false
};
```

```
switch(device.zero.toString() + device.minus10 + device.minus20 + device.minus30 + device.minus40 + device.mode) {
      case "falsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse": 
        indicator.animate({path:"M 265 665 L 160 566"}, 1000, "easeInOut");
        break;
      case "truefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse":
        indicator.animate({path:"M 265 665 L 160 566"}, 1000, "easeInOut");
        break;
      case "falsetruefalsefalsefalsefalse":
        indicator.animate({path:"M 265 665 L 161 564"}, 1000, "easeInOut");
        break;
      case "falsefalsetruefalsefalsefalse":
        indicator.animate({path:"M 265 665 L 162 563"}, 1000, "easeInOut");
        break;
      case "falsefalsefalsetruefalsefalse":
        indicator.animate({path:"M 265 665 L 163 562"}, 1000, "easeInOut");
        break;
      case "falsefalsefalsefalsetruefalse":
        indicator.animate({path:"M 265 665 L 164 561"}, 1000, "easeInOut");
        break;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Just store in `JSON` with the `combination` as the key and the `animate` values can be accessed and used.

Comment: Are values of all flags needed to decide on the outcome in every case?

Comment: Is there 70 distinct SVG paths? You might consider automating the SVG values as it appears only the line to command x & y coordinates change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Treat the `true/false` values as `1/0`, and use them as indexes into a multi-dimensional array:

```
const paths =  
[[[[[[["M 265 665 L 160 566", "M 265 665 L 160 566"],
      ["M 265 665 L 161 564", "M 265 665 L 162 563"]]
     [["M 265 665 L 163 562", "M 265 665 L 164 561"],
...;

var cur_path = paths[Number(device.zero)][Number(device.minus10)][Number(device.minus20)]...;
indicator.animate({path: cur_path}, 1000, "easeInOut");
```

Comment: Fancy, but might be tricky to maintain eh. Cool solution though.

Comment: I think that's true of just about any solution. There are 128 combinations of 7 true/false values.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common use case for bitwise operators. You assign to every boolean property a bit in a number and then using the bitwise OR operator you turn the object into a number which you can can test on in a control structure like a switch.

```
const device = {
    mode: false,
    zero: false,
    minus10: false,
    minus20: false,
    minus30: false,
    minus40: false,
    speed: false
};

let result =
  (0b0000000 |
      device.mode * 2**7 |
      device.zero * 2**6 |
      device.minus10 * 2**5 |
      device.minus20 * 2**4 | 
      device.minus30 * 2**3 |
      device.minus40 * 2**2 |
      device.speed * 2**1 
);
```

So for example, if only `device.mode` is true you get a result of 2^7 (in javascript 2**7) which is 128.

Comment: And to finish the answer, the `L XXX YYY` values can simply be derived by applying an adjustment factor to the the resulting calculation since they seem to be closely synchonized.